# A workout regimen for regaining strength and pleateau breaking?

Tags: bodybuilding, strength-training, training

I have had been training for almost 8 months had gains but then I discovered an inguinal hernia and had a lap. surgery.As I was out from gym I lost muscle mass.**But since am back now,I noticed that I quickly regained the hypertrophy but my stats in core lifts(BP,OHP, SQUAT,DL,BBRow) have gone down considerably.Also,my muscles seem to exhaust more quickly on heavy workloads.**Hence I am struggling to get back my maxes.I need a new plan which will steadyly get to my goals.Am certainly not looking for pure hypertrophy
But  good functional strength and bodyweight control too.My current routine is as such:.

-Push day:
Push ups for warm up 2x15
BP flat 3x10(lost strength, even struggling to lift what used to be my 1st set for warm-up)
21 cable cross over 3x7
Arnold press 3x10
Weighted push up/dips 3xFailure

- Pull day:
  Pull up for warm up 3x8(12-13 rep bodyweight plateau since few weeks)
  BB bend over row 3x8
  Cable lat pulls 3x10
  Db shrugs 3x12
  Cable face pulls 3x12
  Tugged front lever 3xfailure (trying to master front lever )
- legs
  BW squats for warm-up
  BB high squat 3x10 (lost my Max and struggling  at depth during heavy sets)
  Bulgarian split sqts 3x8
  Leg press machine 3x10
  Leg extensions 3x10
  Leg curl 3x10
  Calf raises 3x20
  Hanging leg raises x failure

-Extra day(optional)
DL 3x5(I fear my injury so don't lift too heavy)
Skull crusher 3x10
Triceps extn 3x10
Incline Bicep curl 3x10
Hammer curl 3x10 
Diamond push-up 2xfailure 
Chin up 2x failure

Answer (score 1):

As a first impression. It that is main exercise, for strength I would do 4-6 reps, with weight that guarantee no more reps.

There is no plan that would guarantee progress in long time. That is why people have plan for two weeks, and from that small blocks they build phases. So let's say you are in building strength phase. And you planned it for 2 months, so you have 8 smaller blocks. You can think in opposite direction. You have plan to be in perfect shape next summer. You know that - let's say 3 mounts are needed to cut out fat. So you have 3 mounts of mass training, and another 3 of cutting. Any of that phase you divide into 2 weeks, and plan for them. To better track where you are. In terms of final result. In other words idea with that smaller blocks is to have some kind of stability, but also be able to adjust. Phases on the other hand are to give your body different impulses, so at winter time you can build mass, eat a lot, and going to summer, you can cut calories and work on definition. Other option is to work on strength, and then on stamina, speed, coordination, technic - depends on sport.

For plan preparing... Try with `5-3-1`, or `prilepin chart`. Search over internet, there are Excel spread sheets, but also good explanations why that way. Just try them see how it goes. 2 weeks, and you will see. Usually I'm just performing exercises to maintain more-or-less same level for most muscles, and targeting particular group. Then switching to other group, and so on. That way I can progress, but maybe not that fast.